# Sidewalk Detection

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, semantic-segmentation

I am making an autonomous drone navigation program. I want the drone to continously follow a sidewalk until the user tells it to stop. So, it should be able to capture the sidewalk and highlight in green the region of the sidewalk so that it can follow that until the end.

```
    def color_sidewalk(self, image):
        hsv_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        lower_threshold = np.array([0, 0, 150], dtype=np.uint8)
        upper_threshold = np.array([179, 50, 255], dtype=np.uint8)
        mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_image, lower_threshold, upper_threshold)
        kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5, 5))
        closed = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
        contours, _ = cv2.findContours(closed, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

        sidewalk_contours = []
        for contour in contours:
            perimeter = cv2.arcLength(contour, True)
            if perimeter > 100 and len(contour) > 50:
                sidewalk_contours.append(contour)

        colored_image = np.zeros_like(image)
        if len(sidewalk_contours) > 0:
            cv2.drawContours(colored_image, sidewalk_contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), cv2.FILLED)

        sidewalk_gray = cv2.cvtColor(colored_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        _, sidewalk_mask = cv2.threshold(sidewalk_gray, 1, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
        non_sidewalk_mask = cv2.bitwise_not(sidewalk_mask)
        non_sidewalk_mask = cv2.cvtColor(non_sidewalk_mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
        result = cv2.bitwise_or(cv2.bitwise_and(image, non_sidewalk_mask), colored_image)
        return result
```

This is my code for coloring the sidewalk in green. It works and highlights the right pathway, but sometimes it highlights other things that don't need to be highlighted. I was expecting only the sidewalk to get highlighted. I have attached two examples of this code in action. Additionally, if anyone has any advice on how to use this code to translate it into directions for a drone to travel, it would be greatly appreciated.

Original: [Sidewalk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VcIH.jpg)

Ran through program: [Colored](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meLAf.jpg)

Comment: I have some experience using OpenCV with findContours (I used it to detect different territories on a raster image map and convert that into an SVG that can be edited in JS). I can see that you're already filtering the outputted contours using some criteria. However, these criteria still allow more than one contour to pass through - it seems like you only want one sidewalk at the other end of these tests. I'm no mathematician - and I'm assuming you aren't either - so neither of us can come up with some magic formula that does the work for you. In this area, its just trial and error.

Comment: Add criteria. If its stupid, screw it. Still add it. Eventually you will find something that works. You could literally just start with filtering the sidewalk contours to use the most centrally located contour.

Comment: So basically play around with the thresholds and stuff like that? And do you have any advice on any path finding algorithms that I could use for my drone

Comment: Play around with values, add more criteria when you filter the contours, etc. I'm sorry I don't have a more definitive answer, maybe someone else who knows more about computer vision will. As for pathfinding, that's something I've never dealt with before, so I don't have any personal experience or knowledge.

Comment: I'm just telling you what I did when put in - essentially - the same situation as you. Both areas with pavement are being detected because they look the same to the algorithm. Just try and think how you know it's the one on the left and try to apply that to the algorithm. Maybe you use the one closest to the drone?

Comment: Okay, I tried changing the criteria and it doesn't just highlight unnecessary things so it is pretty good. Thank you for your help!